# GameMaker function causing YoYo Compiler to fail, but not VM

Tags: gml

I am working on making a mod of a mod for "Pizza Tower Online", and I've been getting this weird issue causing YYC to fail, but not VM.
Here is the code snippet causing this:

```
function instance_in_camera(inst = id, cam = view_camera[0])
{
    var camx = camera_get_view_x(cam);
    var camy = camera_get_view_y(cam);
    var camw = camera_get_view_width(cam);
    var camh = camera_get_view_height(cam);

    var result = false;
    var xx = inst.x - sprite_get_xoffset(inst.sprite_index);
    var yy = inst.y - sprite_get_yoffset(inst.sprite_index);

    // left bottom
    result = result || point_in_rectangle(xx + sprite_get_bbox_left(inst.sprite_index), yy + sprite_get_bbox_bottom(inst.sprite_index), camx, camy, camx + camw, camy + camh);
    if (result)
        return result;

    // left top
    if (!result)
    {
        result = result || point_in_rectangle(xx + sprite_get_bbox_left(inst.sprite_index), yy + sprite_get_bbox_top(inst.sprite_index), camx, camy, camx + camw, camy + camh);
        if (result)
            return result;
    }

    // right bottom
    if (!result)
    {
        result = result || point_in_rectangle(xx + sprite_get_bbox_right(inst.sprite_index), yy + sprite_get_bbox_bottom(inst.sprite_index), camx, camy, camx + camw, camy + camh);
        if (result)
            return result;
    }

    // right top
    if (!result)
    {
        result = result || point_in_rectangle(xx + sprite_get_bbox_right(inst.sprite_index), yy + sprite_get_bbox_top(inst.sprite_index), camx, camy, camx + camw, camy + camh);
        if (result)
            return result;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I am using GameMaker 2022.0.0.12 Runtime, 2022.0.0.19 IDE.

I tried changing the |= statements to "result ||", did not work, added a failsafe "return false;" which doesn't work either.
I've also tried to make a "result = false;" in case nothing works, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed - Just don't make "inst" and "cam" optional

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).